# Amazon corretto now includes a bunch of api-ms-win-core-*-l1-1-0.dll files in jre/bin

Tags: java, azul-zulu, corretto

I noticed that [Amazon corretto JRE 8](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/corretto/latest/corretto-8-ug/downloads-list.html) now includes these files in version 8.0.252 (Windows, 32-bit). As far as i know this is new. They are for instance not part of the zulu distribution (same version).

So what is the purpose of these files? Are they needed?